# Trying to run latest eas build on android emulator and getting artifacts error

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I've built my project and ran it before, but now every time I do it I get this in my terminal:

eas build:run -p android --latest

Artifacts for the latest build have expired and are no longer available, or this is not a simulator/emulator build.
Error: build:run command failed.

I can't find any fixes online. I can still run the outdated version of the working build, but any new builds I try have this error message.

I've tried rebuilding, moving the files into a new folder and rebuilding, and running it normally with expo. It runs normally with expo but the new builds of the same app generate this error.

Answer (score 2):

The correct command is the following:

`eas build --platform android`

https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the command `eas build:run -p android --latest` is used to download latest build from eas server and install on the simulator

to make it work you need to first create a build using  `eas build -p android --profile preview`
[Build for Simulators](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/)